# Unable to find element in flipkart search results page

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to find the number of search results being displayed in ([Flipkart e-commerce website](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobile%20phones&otracker=start&as-show=on&as=off)) website using `classname/xpath/cssselector`, but I'm unable to find the total number of results.

The total number is being displayed as a text:

> "Showing 1 – 24 of 8,747 results for "mobile phones"

In the webpage. I'm also unable to identify the number of search items displayed inside each page which is 24 in this case.

The code that I used to find elements is:

```
List<WebElement> flipkartTotalItems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#container > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div._1XdvSH._17zsTh > div > div._2xw3j- > div > div:nth-child(3) > div._2SxMvQ > div > div:nth-child(1)"));


#container > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div._1XdvSH._17zsTh > div > div._2xw3j- > div > div._15eYWX > div > div.KG9X1F > h1 > span
```

I added `thread.sleep` method call for the page to load too.
HTML code for text webelement:

[image]

Comment: @Balwinder Singh -  Thanks for editing my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *url* you have shared to find the number of search results being displayed in [Flipkart Search Result](https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobile%20phones&otracker=start&as-show=on&as=offFlipkart) ecommerce website you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *WebElement* to be visible and then extract the text as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobile%20phones&otracker=start&as-show=on&as=offFlipkart ecommerce website");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='W-gt5y']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='W-gt5y']//ancestor::span")).getText();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='W-gt5y']//ancestor::span")).getText());
```

Console Output :

```
Showing 1 – 24 of 8,753 results for "mobile phones"
```

Comment: This works as expected - was able to get the expected text element. Thanks!

Comment: @SidharthAravinth Upvote this/any answer if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below xpath to locate this "Showing 1 – 24 of 8,747 results for "mobile phones"

```
//*[contains(text(),'Showing 1 – 24 of 8,747 results for')]
```

Below for finding number search result show in a page.

```
//*[@class='_1UoZlX']
```

Comment: When the number of mobile phones changes the first XPath will fail.

Comment: Yes, i agree @Frank.  That was an example. we can simply use partial string and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get the total number of results is to use this xpath

```
//span[contains(text(),'Showing')]
```

Then using "GetText()" get the result using string formatting

```
String result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath>")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is not very friendly for Browser Automation but the most stable xpath for getting the searchresults on a page I think is:

```
List<WebElement> flipkartTotalItems = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//div[@class = 'col col-7-12']"));
```

Getting the length or count of this list wil give you the number of results on the page.